# How to download contents of an account in Solana?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I need to download and deserialize an account with data in Solana from my javascript client. I could not find this in cookbook. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the connection object method (example in typescript)

```js
let account_data = await connection.getAccountInfo(account, "processed");
```

However; this will return a base64 encoded, and program serialized, data block in `account_data.data`.

What you will need to do is to understand how the account data is both structured and serialized in order to deserialize it.